# nonempty open set in normed space is connected iff each pair of points of the set can be joined by a polygon that lies wholly in the set

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a normed vector space. Let $x_1, \dots, x_m$ be points of $E$. Let $f(t) = (k-t)x_k + (t - k + 1) x_{k+1}$ for $k-1 \le t \le k$, $k = 1, 2, \dots, m-1$. The set $\{f(t)\text{ }|\text{ }0 \le t \le m-1\}$ is called a polygon in $E$. How would I go about showing that a nonempty open set $A$ in $E$ is connected if and only if each pair of points of $A$ can be joined by a polygon that lies wholly in $A$?

My progress so far. For the backwards direction, if any two points in $A$ can be joined by a polygon, it is clear that these two points are connected, which means $A$ is connected. But I am not really sure how to go about showing the forwards direction.

Comment: Start by showing that a connected open set is path-connected. Then show that you can approximate every path arbitrarily well by a polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the forwards direction, since $A$ is connected any two points $a, b \in A$ can be connected with a continuous curve $C$ in $A$ with end points, $a, b$. For all $x \in C$ there exists an open ball $$B_{\epsilon_x}(x) = \{y \in E\text{ }|\text{ }\|x - y\| < \epsilon_x\} \subseteq A$$ for some $\epsilon_x > 0$ as $A$ is open. Clearly $$\bigcup_{x \in C} B_{\epsilon_x}(x) \supset C.$$Since $C$ is compact there exists $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \in C$ such that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_{\epsilon_{x_i}}(x_i) \supset C.$$For short, set $U_i = B_{\epsilon_{x_i}}(x_i)$. We also assume that any subset of $\{U_i\text{ }|\text{ }i = 1, \dots, n\}$ cannot cover $C$. Note that each $U_i$ is convex if $x, y \in U_i$ implies the segment $[a, b]$ connecting $a, b$ is also contained in $U_i$. Without loss of generality we can assume$$a \in U_1,\text{ }U_1 \cap U_2 \neq \emptyset,\text{ }U_2 \cap U_3 \neq \emptyset,\text{ }\dots\text{ },\text{ }U_{n-1} \cap U_n \neq \emptyset,\text{ }b \in U_n.$$Take $a_i \in U_i \cap U_{i+1}$, $i = 1, \dots, n-1$. Then we have a polygon$$[a, a_1],\text{ }[a_1, a_2],\text{ }\dots\text{ },\text{ }[a_{n-2}, a_{n-1}],\text{ }[a_{n-1}, b] \subseteq A.$$The proof is complete.